# List functions that use specific table?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Is there any query with which I can list all functions that use specific table?
Something like this (only that works :)):

```
SELECT function_name FROM ? WHERE table = 'my_table';
```

...and this should return me all functions that do something (SELECT, INSERT, whatever) with table 'my_table'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
    JOIN information_schema.parameters ON routines.specific_name=parameters.specific_name
WHERE routines.specific_schema='public' AND routine_definition like '%table_name%'
ORDER BY routines.routine_name, parameters.ordinal_position;
```